# Passing in variable for finding elements with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm devloping this programing to do some automation tasks in python with selenium. The user is prompted to input their project name. The program will then open the website up and select the project with the same name as the user inputted. I am going to select the element using xpath. However if there are many projects on the site they all have the same `class`. So I thought I could use xpath to select the class but pass in `//text(user_sproject_name_here)`. Here is the xpath that I have and the html I am trying to select.

HTML Elements(leaving href blank because it will not work out how I want the program to be if I use it):

```
<a href = "" class = "js-filter-text">
                            Test_1
```

```
<a href = "" class = "js-filter-text">
                            Test_2
</a>
```

For example the text I wanted to look for is "Test_1" but the user would input this and it could select the correct element based off the text.

Here is what I have for xpath. I dont know how to pass in a variable for `//text()`

```
element3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class= "js-filter-text"]//text()' ).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think the following should work:

```
element3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="js-filter-text" and contains(text(), "{}")]'.format(input_variable)).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, when I try this in my program with .click() at the end I get this error. 

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' `

Comment: I went along with your syntax, but I just realised it should be 'find_element_by_xpath' not 'find_elements_by_xpath'. The former returns a list which you can't 'click'. Let me know if that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class= "js-filter-text"]//text(),' " + variablename + " '')
```